# How to filter the latest version of every file in a tree using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a mid-sized directory-tree with variety of files:

- /some/place/distfiles/foo-1.2.jar
- /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
- /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.jar
- /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar

I use the [find-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) to get the full list, but I only need the *latest* versions for each *foo* and *bar*. The above set, for example, needs to be reduced to:

- /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
- /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar

No, I cannot rely on the files' timestamps -- only on the numerical parts of the filenames...

Can someone suggest an elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

It will be some non-trivial amount of jinja2, so you may be happier writing a custom module so you can work in an actual programming language (you can still use `find:` and `register:` to capture the list of filenames, and then give it to your custom module to roll up the "latest" for each file based on your rules)

That said, I would guess the [`version` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) can be used to find the newest after you have split the items into `tuple[str, str]` from its basename to its version number:

```yaml
- find:
    paths:
    - /some/place/distfiles
    # etc
  register: my_jars
- set_fact:
    versions_by_filename: >-
       {%- set results = {} -%}
       {%- for f in my_jars.files -%}
       {%-   set bn = f.path | basename 
             | regex_replace(ver_regex, '\\1') -%}
       {%-   set v = f.path | regex_replace(ver_regex, '\\2') -%}
       {%-   set _ = results.setdefault(bn, []).append(v) -%}
       {%- endfor -%}
       {{ results }}
  vars:
    ver_regex: '(.*)-([0-9.-]+)\.jar'

- set_fact:
    most_recent: >-
       {%- set results = {} -%}
       {%- for fn, ver_list in versions_by_filename.items() -%}
       {%-   set tmp = namespace(latest=ver_list[0]) -%}
       {%-   for v in ver_list -%}
       {%-      if tmp.latest is version(v, '<') -%}
       {%-        set tmp.latest = v -%}
       {%-      endif -%}
       {%-   endfor -%}
       {%-   set _ = results.update({fn: tmp.latest}) -%}
       {%- endfor -%}
       {{ results }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's transform the data for this purpose first. For example

```
   - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ result.files|json_query('[].path') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_files
```

gives

```
  my_files:
  - /some/place/distfiles/foo-1.2.jar
  - /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.jar
  - /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar
  - /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
```

Create a list of dictionaries

```
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict
                    |default([]) + [
                     dict(['path', 'archive', 'version']
                          |zip([item,
                                (item|basename).split('-')[0],
                                (item|basename).split('-')[1]|splitext|list|first])) ] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_dict
```

gives

```
  my_dict:
  - archive: foo
    path: /some/place/distfiles/foo-1.2.jar
    version: '1.2'
  - archive: bar
    path: /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.jar
    version: '1.1'
  - archive: bar
    path: /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar
    version: 1.1.2
  - archive: foo
    path: /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
    version: '1.3'
```

Group the items by the name of the archive

```
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_dict|groupby('archive') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_groups
```

gives

```
  my_groups:
  - - bar
    - - archive: bar
        path: /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.jar
        version: '1.1'
      - archive: bar
        path: /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar
        version: 1.1.2
  - - foo
    - - archive: foo
        path: /some/place/distfiles/foo-1.2.jar
        version: '1.2'
      - archive: foo
        path: /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
        version: '1.3'
```

When the data is ready find the latest versions and print the results

```
    - debug:
        msg: "Latest version of {{ item.0 }} is {{ item.1|json_query(query)|first }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?version == '{{ latest_version }}'].path"
        latest_version: "{{ item.1|json_query('[].version')|max }}"
      loop: "{{ my_groups }}"
```

gives

```
  msg: Latest version of bar is /some/place/distfiles/bar-1.1.2.jar
  msg: Latest version of foo is /some/place/distfiles/subdir/foo-1.3.jar
```

---

Notes

- Problem with filter [max](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters)

> Credit @mdaniel: *"max suffers from the long-standing problem of trying to use a lexicographical sort for version numbers, as it claims that of the choices 1.2 and 1.10, that 1.2 is the 'latest'"*

It's possible to create a [custom filter plugin](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/version_filters/version_filters.py) with the filter and use it to select the latest version. For example

```
$ cat filter_plugins/version_filters.py

from distutils.version import LooseVersion

def version_max(l):
    return sorted(l, key=LooseVersion)[-1]

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'version_max' : version_max
            }
```

```
latest_version: "{{ item.1|json_query('[].version')|version_max }}"
```

- The play expects that the filenames have the format

```
<archive>-<version>.<extension>
```

Comment: As a friendly FYI, your use of `max` suffers from the long-standing problem of trying to use a lexigraphical sort for version numbers, as it claims that of the choices `1.2` and `1.10`, that `1.2` is the "latest"; it is still possible to use `max`, but one would need to decompose the version numbers into their constituent parts, since major.minor.patch.whatever each have their own "max", and at that point one has just reinvented a version comparison test

Comment: Right. Thank you. I've added a custom filter.